# Retract of a torus.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $T= \mathbb{S^1} \times \mathbb{S^1} $ denote the two dimensional torus and let $W = \mathbb{S^1} \vee \mathbb{S^1} $. I don't know how to show that $W$ is not a retract of $T$. Thanks for helping.

Comment: What have you tried? What are your definitions for "retract"? A lot of context is needed for a problem like this, I fear.

Comment: I need to show that the identity map on W does not admit a continuous extension $r: T \rightarrow W$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental group of the torus is $Z\oplus Z$ and the fundamental group of $W$ is the free group generated by two elements.